# C# Slider On Release method

Tags: c#, kinect

I am trying to use C#'s slider to do some basic kinect angle control. My problem now is that I need a handler method that will only react after I let go of the slider button. I tried usng ManipulationEnded but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Is there such a method in C# that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using WPF? I just made a quick test for this, and it seems like you want to try the `LostMouseCapture` event.

In the .xaml

```
<Slider ... LostMouseCapture="slider1_LostMouseCapture" />
```

In the .cs file:

```
private void slider1_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("New value: {0}", slider1.Value);
}
```

Note that this won't be caught if the user uses a keyboard to adjust the slider (arrow keys). If you're okay with that, you can set the Slider to not be focusable.